# PyTuple_Pack which takes in variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, python

I am on Python 2.6.6 & calling python from c++ .

How can i write PyTuple_Pack which takes in variable number of arguments .

I have variable arguments coming which I use a for loop and populate my array . My array has max of 1000 elements but i populate only top no_of_argument elements using

```
python_obj[i] = PyString_FromString(arg[i])
```

I DO NOT want to write code like

```
if(no_of arg ==1 )
    return  PyTuple_Pack(1, python_obj[0]);
if(no_of arg ==2 )
    return  PyTuple_Pack(2, python_obj[0],python_obj[1]);
```

I want something like 
     return PyTuple_Pack(no_of_args, followed by my array where pyobjects exist ;

On net i can see http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/whatsnew/node14.html

```
A new function, PyTuple_Pack(N, obj1, obj2, ..., objN), constructs tuples from a variable length argument list of Python objects. (Contributed by Raymond Hettinger.)
```

However example to write good code using above is not found by my search for which i need your help pls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PyTuple_New` to make a tuple with the right size, then iterate over your array and use `PyTuple_SetItem` to fill the tuple with values.

Comment: Note that `PyTuple_SET_ITEM` is probably a better choice than `PyTuple_SetItem` for filling in new tuples.